# Including plugin javascript on the client side

Tags: plugin-development, javascript

I've created a simple plugin based on the Craft docs with the following directory structure...

```
/craft
    /plugins
        /eforms
            /resources
                /js
                    public.js
            /templates
                /public
                    index.html
/public_html
```

In the index.html template of my plugin I'm using the following line to try to include the public.js file...

```
{% includeJsResource "eforms/js/public.js" %}
```

Which attempts to include the following resource in the browser

```
http://mydomain/eforms/js/public.js
```

Unfortunately this just gives me a 404. Does anyone have an idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Think you need:

```
UrlHelper::getResourceUrl('path/to/file.ext')
```

There is more info over at http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/resources

### Edit

ok, scrap that answer, I didn't read the rest of the help page :)

I think you are nearly there though. I'll have a test on my local machine and get back to you.

### Edit 2

I believe I'm running into the same problem you have described as well. I did however get it working by doing this:

```
<script src="{{ resourceUrl('eforms/js/public.js') }}"></script>
```

Comment: I appreciate the effort but unfortunately this file needs to appear after a number of others so I must use the includeJsResource method.